# Conexion Remota fallida con MongoDB AYUDA

Tags: java, netbeans, mongodb, mongoose

La verdad soy  novato en programación y tengo una tarea que me esta dando dolor de cabeza.

Es crear una base de datos en `MongoDB` que sincronice con los datos con una aplicación en `Java` en `NetBeans`. A mi me sale, inserta los datos y aparece en mi base de datos.
El problema esta cuando hago conexión remota con otras computadoras, a mis amigos les aparece este error.

> com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection ADVERTENCIA: Exception
>   executing isMaster command on Jorge-Luis-Julian-Sanchez/(mi IP)27017
>   java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to
>   [Jorge-Luis-Julian-Sanchez/(MI IP):27017]
>   bc:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out     at
>   com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)     at
>   com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)    at
>   com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88)     at
>   com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148)    at
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:544)
>     at com.mongodb.Mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize(Mongo.java:600)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:233)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:205)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57)     at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:100)    at
>   pruebamongo.InsertSQL.main(InsertSQL.java:44)

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, MongoDB no permite conexiones remotas.
Tendrás que habilitar el acceso en el fichero mongod.conf añadiendo:

> bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, TU_IP_PRIVADA

Como ambos están en la misma red LAN, solo necesitas vincular MongoDB a tu propia interfaz IP privada.

[Más información](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás corriendo la base de datos localmente, normalmente mongoDB corre en localhost:27017. Para que se sincroniza en otras maquinas tienes que colocar tu base de datos en un servidor web por ejemplo, otra opción es que localmente cada maquina que va a utilizar el programa también ejecute mongoDB